# Loading jquery after inserting the jquery tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I insert the jquery tag

```
    var newScript = document.createElement("script");
        newScript.id = "grazit_jq";
        newScript.type = "text/javascript"           
        newScript.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js";
        script.parentNode.appendChild(newScript);
```

And after that I want to check if jquery exists.

I do so in a few ways.One way is like this:

```
     var checkJquery=function(){
        if(typeof(jQuery) === 'undefined')
        {
           console.log('jQuery doesnt exist');
            window.setTimeout(arguments.callee,1000);
            return;
        }
        else{
        sprk_lib=new sprk();
           sprk_lib.load(jQuery);
        }
    };
  sprk.prototype.load=function($){


 console.log($);
```

};
        **UPDATE**
Now i updated the code. It will call the function as soon as the jQuery object is availeable.

In that function I will execute my jquery code. Do you think that there will be problems? is it okay to do it that way?

> original

I wait there. problem is that in the console log , it returns null and the prints jQuery exists. How can I stop the script till the jquery is loaded,, and then continue executing the script?

Answer (score 2):

Consider using an established JavaScript script loader such as [LABjs](http://labjs.com/) or [LazyLoad](https://github.com/rgrove/lazyload/) which offer reliable callbacks that don't fire until the script has fully loaded.

Check out [this summary of 5 JavaScript script loaders](http://www.netmagazine.com/features/essential-javascript-top-five-script-loaders).

For example:

```
LazyLoad.js('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js', function () {
  console.log('jQuery exists!');
  console.log('Document title: ' + $("title").text());
});
```

One point of note - if you want to hold off all further script execution until after jQuery has loaded, you could put the rest of your script inside this callback function. However, that would break a whole load of best practices (separation of concerns, loose coupling etc) so your best bet is to pass an existing function as your callback, which can in turn call out to other functions etc. For example:

```
function doSomething() {
  console.log('I am doing something!')
  doSomethingElse();
}

function doSomethingElse() {
  console.log('I am doing something else!');
}

LazyLoad.js('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js', doSomething);
```

You could further improve your application architecture (e.g. by introducing [PubSub](http://addyosmani.com/blog/tag/pubsub/)) but that's getting outside the scope of this question so I'll leave it there.

Comment: see ujpdate.. your solution isnt ideal

Comment: @BlackFire27 I'm not entirely clear what you mean as your updated post is a little bit garbled. It reads a bit as though you're asking if it's ok to continue your script execution from within the callback, in which case the answer is yes. I've updated this answer with an additional example in case that helps. If it doesn't then please further clarify your question.